# RMySQL connection with --secure_auth=false

Tags: security, authentication, rmysql

I need to get data from an old MySQL server and I'm getting the following error when trying to connect to it with RMySQL or DBI packages:

`Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)`

On terminal, I must use the '--secure_auth=false' option to be able to connect to that MySQL server, but I'cant handle how to use it with RMySQL and DBI packages.

Reading these packages docs, I've found the `default.file` arg to use in cdbConnect() functions. So I've created a '.my.cnf' file with 'secure_auth=false' direction (following MySQL documentation). But with this conf file the dbConnect() function crashed.

With RJDBC package, I can connect to that server, even without any extra option to set secure_auth. But I would like to use RMySQL to do that, since I am already using it to many other connections in the same script and also because RMySQL is more updated than RJDBC.

My sessionInfo():

`R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] RJDBC_0.2-5       rJava_0.9-8       DT_0.1            reshape2_1.4.1    RAdwords_0.1.9

 [6] RGA_0.4.2         highcharter_0.3.0 ggplot2_2.1.0     lubridate_1.5.6   dplyr_0.4.3

[11] gpbR_1.0          RMySQL_0.10.9     DBI_0.4-1`